# How to use ORDER BY to sort by multiple sorting conditions

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I want to write a query which will sort the results based on multiple conditions.

Please refer to following dummy table

| name | domain |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | gmail |
| .Apple2 | yahoo |
| _Apple3 | xyz |
| Apple4 | zyx |
| Ball | abc |
| .Ball2 | efg |
| _Ball3 | gmail |
| Ball4 | yahoo |
| Bear | xyz |
| Cat | abc |

I want to sort above table

1 - By Known domain `yahoo` followed by `gmail` then rest.

So I want to divide result rows in three parts.

1st section with rows having `yahoo` as domain then in 2nd section rows with `gmail` domain at last rest of the rows.

2 - Alphabetically and all special characters at the end.

Every section should be further sorted alphabetically on `name` field with special characters at the end.

Result should look like following table.

| name | domain |
| --- | --- |
| Ball4 | yahoo |
| .Apple2 | yahoo |
| Apple | gmail |
| _Ball3 | gmail |
| Apple4 | zyx |
| Ball | abc |
| Bear | xyz |
| Cat | abc |
| _Apple3 | xyz |
| .Ball2 | efg |

I have managed to sort result alphabetically with special symbols at bottom with following query but I am not able to get the 1st part of sorting correct i.e sort by known domain.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN name GLOB '[A-Za-z]*'
          THEN name
          ELSE '~' || name
          END COLLATE NOCASE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY domain = 'yahoo' DESC,
         domain = 'gmail' DESC,
         name GLOB '[A-Za-z]*' DESC,
         LTRIM(LTRIM(name, '.'), '_');
```

Each of these boolean expressions evaluates to `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1d579d06c0baef9885efe28ccf51835d).

Comment: Thanks forpas. 
Your solutions is working as expected. Can you please add some details about why we need LTRIM(LTRIM(name, '.'), '_'). I am not able to understand.

Comment: @DCoder after the first 3 conditions have been applied the names should be sorted (as I understand) alphabetically, but for the names starting with special chars these special chars should be stripped off from the beginning, so that what is left is used for the alphabetical sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 - To sort by specific values first you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN domain = 'yahoo' then 0 
           WHEN domain = 'gmail' then 1
           ELSE 2
         END ASC
```

Part 2 - Then within that you want to sort by name, so add your existing name sorting to our ORDER BY so we have this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN domain = 'yahoo' then 0 
           WHEN domain = 'gmail' then 1
           ELSE 2
         END ASC,
 CASE WHEN name GLOB '[A-Za-z]*'
          THEN name
          ELSE '~' || name
          END COLLATE NOCASE
```

Answer (score 0):

May not the most performant solution, but it should work with a union in such special cases:

```
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table1
  WHERE
    domain like 'yahoo'
  ORDER BY
    name desc
)
UNION
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE
      domain like 'gmail'
    ORDER BY
      name desc
  )
UNION
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE
      domain not like 'yahoo'
      OR domain not like 'gmail'
    ORDER BY
      domain desc,
      name desc
  )
```